# StaleWhileRevalidate: Remove from cache once a non-success status is encountered

Tags: javascript, service-worker, workbox

We’re using Workbox’s `StaleWhileRevalidate` strategy to cache responses of a JSON API. Under normal circumstances, this API will respond with a status code of 200 and deliver the desired data.

However, it might happen that a user should no longer have access to that data. In that case, our JSON API responds with status `401`.

Unfortunately, our app still “sees” the cached JSON response.

Are there any settings or hooks in Workbox which I could use to prune a cached entry, once we encounter a `401`? Or is there any other advice or best practice to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend writing a custom plugin that used the [`cacheWillUpdate`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/using-plugins#custom_plugins) callback, and took appropriate action if the status of the incoming `Response` is `401`. (`workbox-cacheable-response` uses `cacheWillUpdate` under the hood, but you need more flexibility, so writing your own logic makes sense.)

Something like:

```
// Or use workbox.core.cacheNames.runtime for the default cache.
const cacheName = 'my-api-cache';

const myPlugin = {
  cacheWillUpdate: async ({response}) => {
    if (response.status === 401) {
      const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
      await cache.delete(response.url);
      return null;
    }

    // Add in any other checks here, if needed.
    return response;
  },
};

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /^\/api\/data.json$/,
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName,
    plugins: [myPlugin],
  })
);
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I definitely like this better!

Answer (score 0):

So, here’s my workaround:

I used the `workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin` to allow caching a `401` response. Then, I added another plugin, which checks whether the cached response was successful. If not (i.e. `401` received), I’ll return no cache result:

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /^\/api\/data.json$/,
  new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
    plugins: [
      // explicitly allow to cache `401` …
      new workbox.cacheableResponse.Plugin({ statuses: [0, 200, 401] }),
      // … but do not return a cached result
      // in this case (!cachedResponse.ok)
      {
        cachedResponseWillBeUsed: ({ cachedResponse }) => {
          return (cachedResponse && cachedResponse.ok) ? cachedResponse : null;
        }
      }
    ]
  })
);
```